# What is a parent promise?

Tags: r, promise, pryr

In package `pryr`, there is a function called `parent_promise`.

I know what a promise is, but I'm not familiar with the term *parent promise*. Furthermore, I don't really understand the example in the documentation, perhaps because I don't know what I'm looking for.

```
library(pryr)
example(parent_promise)
# prnt_p> f <- function(x) g(x)
# prnt_p> g <- function(y) h(y)
# prnt_p> h <- function(z) parent_promise(z)
# prnt_p> h(x + 1)
# x + 1
# prnt_p> g(x + 1)
# x + 1
# prnt_p> f(x + 1)
# x + 1
```

To help me get a better understanding of the above example, can someone explain what a *parent promise* is, and if/how it differs from a regular promise?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no special thing called a "parent promise." There are just promises. But a promise might point to another promise. The `parent_promise` function basically walks up the chain of promises to find the first non-promise.

So when you call `f(x)`, that in turn calls `g(y)` with `y (promise)-> x`. Since you never evaluate `y`, that parameter is passed along as a promise to `h(z)` with `z (promise)-> y`. So

```
z (promise)-> y (promise)-> x (promise)-> x+1
```

So calling `parent_promise(z)` goes up the chain to find the first non-promise object which in each of these cases is the expression `x+1`

Comment: So, if the parent promise points to another promise, and the parent promise is evaluated, does that mean all other promises in the chain are evaluated?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you're getting at. In order to resolve a promise, you must evaluate everything up the chain. And once it's resolved, you can't point a new promise to original promise any more so they chain can't descend.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was asking.

Comment: BTW I'd now recommend looking at https://github.com/hadley/lazy for related functions and documentation and vignettes